# I have no idea what's going on with the screen

Tags: graphics, display, screen

Hi I just switched from windows to Ubuntu 14.10 and I have no idea what's going on with the screen. When I log in I see red lines everywhere and it makes it almost impossible to read anything. At first I thought it MIGHT be screen resolution so I turned it down and it goes from red lines to an ungodly blur. I'm no pro with Ubuntu but I've tried getting district update, purging and reinstalling the nvidea drivers everything I can think of and nothing is working please help.

Comment: What type of graphics card do you have? Maybe add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question. Are you using the open source drivers (nouveau) or Nvidia's binary drivers (nvidia-driver)?

Answer (score 0):

With: CTRL + ALT + F2

You can shut down the GUI. Login with your username.

**Installation without X / from the console
From Ubuntu 14.04 and up**

The jockey-text command was removed with the release of Ubuntu 14.04. You can now use ubuntu-drivers to get the list of packages for each driver, and then install the packages using apt-get. For example:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DDAsv000017AAsd000021D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

After the installation:

```
reboot
```